# routing in Anto.Abp.Microservice.Template

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, abp

I hope I explain the error well,
I'm having a problem with the Tasky.Gateway application and exclusively in routing from Tasky.Blazor application to any new service.
Tasky,Gateway swagger only sees in main cluster in appsettings.json file .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdBMz.png)

If I request data from the Blazor application, it gives me this error

This_console_error:7  fail: Tasky.Blazor.Pages.Currencies.Currencies[0]
Could not found remote action for method: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos.PagedResultDto`1[Tasky.CurrencyService.Currencies.CurrencyDto]] GetListAsync(Tasky.CurrencyService.Currencies.CurrencyPagedAndSortedResultRequestDto) on the URL: https://localhost:7500
Volo.Abp.AbpException: Could no

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NdMQ.png)

I put currency cluster replace main cluster it  fetch data correct
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ5NX.png)
like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFADD.png)
but problem is This is an incorrect method to fix problem and role and users hidden

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.